# How to change HTTP response and show an error message when exception happens in destructor?

Tags: php, exception, destructor

I have a situation where a PHP function attempts to redirect the browser via an HTTP 302, but an exception is being thrown in a destructor called upon 'exit'ing.  The actual code in question is [the _doRedirect() method of SimpleSAML](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/master/lib/SimpleSAML/Utilities.php#L566) but here's a simplified situation:

```
header('Location: http://somewhere.com', TRUE, 302);
exit; // end script execution
```

The 'exit' is triggering a destructor for an unrelated class and the error details are getting written out to the HTTP response... but no human notices the error because the browser executes the HTTP 302 redirect.

Ideally I'd like to change the status code to HTTP 500 so the browser would just render the page with the error on it.  But is that possible?  If not, what options do I have?

Comment: Have you tried it? What were the results?

Comment: Tried what? I'm not sure how to adapt the http response to the exception being generated by the destructor.

Comment: I think an exception should change the response code to 500 ISE. If (I am mistaken and) it does not, trap the exception and send the 500 response code yourself.

Comment: @Salman I hoped so too, but the exception happens and the status code is not changed to a 500.  I'd love to trap the exception myself, but how?

Comment: Hmmm... the status cannot be changed if some output was sent. Is there an `echo` statement between `header(...)` call and the exception?

Comment: yes there are multiple echo's after the header() call, but even so I believe I'd still have to trap the exception anyway

Comment: IMHO you should avoid this situation by getting rid of the destructors. Or at least the ones that cause errors/exceptions. Destructor are meant to close/free external resources, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are meeting a <kbd>by-design</kbd> issue.

- The [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function does not handle uncaught exceptions (which is a level E_ERROR error):

From the documentation:

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined
>   function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING,
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the
>   file where set_error_handler() is called.

- The [reguster_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) function is called after your `exit` call (or when the end of the script is reached), but before your objects destruction.

So if you are trying such code:

```
<?php

register_shutdown_function(function() {
  $error = error_get_last();
  if (!is_null($error)) {
    header_remove();
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    // do something with $error
  }
  else {
    echo "no error happened";
  }
});

class A
{
   public function __destruct()
   {
     throw new \Exception("Hey dude!");
   }
}

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
$a = new A;
```

You'll get "no error happened" and the fatal error displayed, and the 301 will remain unchanged.

[image]

If you think you may destroy your object from inside the `register_shutdown_function` callback, you'll meet a scoping issue where your object is referenced in its original scope, and in the `register_shutdown_function`'s scope: as one reference of the object still exist, it will not be destroyed.

```
<?php

class A
{
   public function __destruct()
   {
     throw new \Exception("Hey dude!");
   }
}

$a = new A; /* global scope */

register_shutdown_function(function() use ($a /* local scope */) {
  try {
    unset($a); /* removed from local scope but another reference still exists in global scope */
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Catched!\n";
  }
});

/* destructor called here */
```

---

Even well-known debug components do not support this.

For example using the [Symfony2 Debug](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/debug/introduction.html) component:

<kbd>composer.json</kbd>

```
{
  "require": {
    "symfony/debug": "~2.5"
  }
}
```

<kbd>test.php</kbd>

```
<?php

require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

Debug::enable();

class A
{
   public function __destruct()
   {
     throw new \Exception("Hey dude!");
   }
}

$a = new A;
```

The component is enabled but does not display the nice expected exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sequence of events is as follows:

```
/* 1 */ header("Location: /some/path");
/* 2 */ echo "Some content";
/* 3 */ exit;
/* 3.1 */ throw new Exception("Some exception");
```

When content is sent in step #2, PHP *has to* send the header as well which is set to 302. Once the header is sent, an exception cannot change the status code. The error message generated is ignored by the browser as it navigates away to the specified location.

Solution:

You can try adding `ob_start()` to start buffering at a *suitable location*. By suitable location I mean anywhere before the step 1 in the above illustration. Buffering defers the sending of header and/or content until page is processed (or buffer is flushed explicitly). This *might* give PHP a chance to alter response code and header.

Comment: This is exactly what we did in order to actually use 301s/302s in WordPress (for example).  Started with ob_start() (which CAN be nested, by the way!), set some kind of 'OK' flag (even something simple like $no_errors = TRUE;), and then at the very end, we had a final check: if ($no_errors = TRUE) { ob_end_flush() } else { // handle errors, etc. }

Comment: NB: The output buffering solution is about suppressing the redirect, not for handling the exception/error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is the library you are using that is forcing the redirect. I am not sure why but I would probably advise not hacking that. One option would be to store the error in [flash data](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#flash-data) from the class that is throwing it and then on the page it is redirecting to, if flash data exists then display the error. This way you are not having to worry about accidentally updating simpleSAML and having it break again or other unintended issues.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#flash-data

Comment: the flash technique would work for reacting to the error, but unfortunately right now I don't have a way to "notice" the error in the first place.

Comment: Where you linked to in the code, it looks like that method is called by `::redirect` and it is mentioned it is being deprecated and replaced by either `redirectTrustedURL` or `redirectUntrustedURL`. Can you see where you are calling `SimpleSAML_Utilities::redirect` in your project and change your project's behavior there?

Comment: There are 9 SimpleSAML methods in the stacktrace that are above the call to redirect(), so unfortunately it's not a top-level thing I can change.

Comment: is it possible after the redirect to call loadExceptionState?  `$state = SimpleSAML_Auth_State::loadExceptionState();` then `$exception = $state[SimpleSAML_Auth_State::EXCEPTION_DATA];` and display $exception if not empty?

Comment: the _doRedirect() method calls exit() explicitly so I don't believe I have the opportunity to inspect anything (since exit() aborts everything else), right?