# How to print a message when an exception is thrown in a destructor triggered by exit() in php?

Tags: php, exception

I have PHP code like this:

```
<?php
class MyDestructableClass {
   function __destruct() {
       print "Destroying MyDestructableClass";
       throw new Exception('Intentionally thrown exception, can it be caught?');
   }
}

$obj = new MyDestructableClass();

exit;  // Triggers destructor eventually

?>
```

I want to print a special message when the destructor happens (and an exception is thrown) when the exit() occurs.  I can't modify the contents of MyDestructableClass itself, I just want to notice when its destructor throws an exception.

I've tried an exception handler:

```
<?php
class MyDestructableClass {
   function __destruct() {
       print "Destroying MyDestructableClass";
       throw new Exception('Intentionally thrown exception, can it be caught?');
   }
}

$obj = new MyDestructableClass();

function myExceptionHandler($exception)
{
  print "I noticed an exception was thrown, success!";
}

set_exception_handler('myExceptionHandler');

exit;  // Triggers destructor eventually

?>
```

but nothing prints.

I've also tried a shutdown function:

```
<?php
class MyDestructableClass {
   function __destruct() {
       print "Destroying MyDestructableClass";
       throw new Exception('Intentionally thrown exception, can it be caught?');
   }
}

$obj = new MyDestructableClass();

function myShutdownFunction()
{
  if (error_get_last() != NULL)  // Only want to react to errors, not normal shutdown
  {
    print "I noticed an exception was thrown, success!";
  }
}

register_shutdown_function('myShutdownFunction');

exit;  // Triggers destructor eventually

?>
```

but nothing prints.

What technique can notice the exception in the destructor that is initiated by exit()?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. But I don't know if it is what you want.

```
<?php

class MyDestructableClass {
    function __destruct() {
        print "Destroying MyDestructableClass";
        throw new Exception('Intentionally thrown exception, can it be caught?');
    }
}


function RunEverything(){
    $obj = new MyDestructableClass();
}

try {
    RunEverything();

} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'My error has been thrown';
}


exit;
/*
 */

?
```

Comment: I will clarify the question.  Your code works, but I need the exit() to be the trigger of the destructor.

Comment: May I ask why? Does it have to be exit()? Or could it maybe be my_exit(); (I don't have an solution yet using my_exit(); but it might be good to know)

Comment: absolutely.  My question here is an boiled-down version of the full problem I'm facing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186963/how-to-change-http-response-and-show-an-error-message-when-exception-happens-in) where an exit() is forced upon me by an included library.

Comment: Do you know what instance/instances might trigger the exceptions? Can you force the destructor(s) to execute before the exit();?

Comment: unfortunately no, the instance that throws the exception is encapsulated by multiple outer classes.

Comment: And you can't trigger the destructor of the outermost class which would cause a ripple of destructors?

Comment: I like the idea, but the first call to the outermost class is the one that eventually results in the exit(), so there's no opportunity to trigger the destructor before exit() is called